# Unable to create a new angular project using npm as packagemanager

Tags: angular

I am unable to create a new Angular project. I've set the packagemanager as npm. npm config set registry is at https://registry.npmjs.org/ still It is not working:

> ```
> C:\Angular>ng new project1
> ? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
> ? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
> CREATE project1/angular.json (3609 bytes)
> CREATE project1/package.json (1294 bytes)
> CREATE project1/README.md (1026 bytes)
> CREATE project1/tsconfig.json (543 bytes)
> CREATE project1/tslint.json (1953 bytes)
> CREATE project1/.editorconfig (246 bytes)
> CREATE project1/.gitignore (631 bytes)
> CREATE project1/browserslist (429 bytes)
> CREATE project1/karma.conf.js (1020 bytes)
> CREATE project1/tsconfig.app.json (270 bytes)
> CREATE project1/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/index.html (294 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/polyfills.ts (2838 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/app/app.component.html (25498 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (987 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/app/app.component.ts (212 bytes)
> CREATE project1/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
> CREATE project1/e2e/protractor.conf.js (808 bytes)
> CREATE project1/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
> CREATE project1/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (641 bytes)
> CREATE project1/e2e/src/app.po.ts (262 bytes)
> 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> Package install failed, see above.
> ```

Comment: you can try to install `yarn` manually by `npm i -g yarn` then retry the ng create cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Try npm cache clean then do the new command again

```
npm cache clean
```

As it seems the project related files have been created and the package.json is also created you can do Npm install commad like below

```
npm i
```

The above command will again install/add the project depend libraries of angular and you start with your project